# Generic openid -connect client libraries (server-keycloak)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, google-oauth, openid-connect, keycloak

[Keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) is my OpenID Connect Provider. My legacy application which uses a local authentication mechanism now needs to be upgraded to use the standard OpenId Connect. I use Jboss 5 as the application server on which my legacy applications are deployed. The legacy application uses java 6 which is another reason, I cannot use keycloak client library directly.

From the [official](http://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html)  documentation it seems that (client) support for JBoss 5 does not exist. I would therefore like to use a library to do the work for me. Any recommendations on the libraries? I dont find a lot of examples out there on the web.

Also, is there any need for client libraries at all, since there are REST API's exposed which I can consume directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to finally settle for [google's client API.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/)

The support for openID connect is still Beta and there has not been an update to the library for the past nine months. So had to directly parse the JWT tokens instead of the library doing the work for me. The library can be used with JAVA 5 and above which is a big plus for legacy applications.

Comment: Eager to know,  do use external OAuth service. to authenticate you applications.

Comment: We use Keycloak as our external Oauth service.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `keycloak-admin-client` , it uses Keycloak REST API to connect to KeyCloak Server.

Comment: You can check the REST APIs provided by KeyCloak  for OpenId connections here  https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/v/2.4/topics/oidc/oidc-generic.html